# C++ List_tail_remove debug

Tags: c++, debugging, linked-list

I'm not how to debug this one function of my code, When I remove and output my linked list it gives me a funky decimal. Any help would be appreciated.

```
void list_tail_remove(node*& head_ptr)
{
    if (head_ptr == NULL)
    {
        cout << "Error:The Double linked List was never Created" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        node* current = head_ptr;
        while (current->link() != NULL)
        {
            current = current->link();
        }

        node* temp;
        for (temp = head_ptr; temp != current; temp = temp->link())
        {
            temp = temp->link();
        }
        temp->set_link(NULL);
        delete temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: What compiler and operating system are you using?  Also, I think your for-loop conditional should be temp->link() != current.  At the end of your for loop, temp *is* current, in order to break the loop.

Comment: ... and you should then delete `current`, not `temp`.